# When did the daily export of Firebase data to Bigquery take place?

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, firebase-analytics

I have enabled the BigQuery integration in Firebase Console for more than a week now and I noticed that:

1. The daily export data is only up to D-2 when it should be D-1
2. The Intraday dataset usually contains up to 2 days of data

So I want to know if there is any config or where I can find at what time do the daily export of Firebase data takes place? And if possible how do I change it?

Comment: Hi,
I am facing the same issue, were you able to solve it.